# Wordpress Loop inside taxonomy php file CPT Filter By Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have this custom post type loop inside taxonomy.php file on wordpress working fine.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    //added before to ensure it gets opened
    echo '<div class="row">';
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'publica', 'posts_per_page' => 6));
    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
            // post stuff...
            ?>

            <div class="col s12 m4">
                <div class="notboxes">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'responsive-img')); ?></a>
                    <?php get_the_term_list($id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after) ?> 

                    <span class="litletimebox"><?php the_time('H:i'); ?> | <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'comision-publicaciones') ?></span>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                    <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="waves-effect waves-light btn abbutton amber lighten-1">Leer Más</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            // if multiple of 3 close div and open a new div
            if ($i % 3 == 0)
            {
                echo '<div style="clear:both"></div></div><div class="row">';
            }
            $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    //make sure open div is closed
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
</div>
```

I bring the number of the taxonomy by using this

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$ter_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

But when I put the `cat = $ter_id` to filter the taxonomy

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'publica', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'cat' => $ter_id));
```

It wont load on the page.

So I've been searching on the web and I found this loop that pulls all taxonomys with its posts.

```
<?php

$custom_terms = get_terms('comision-publicaciones');
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'publica',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'comision-publicaciones',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <a href=""><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile;
     }
}

?>
```

This works perfect in my need, but just need the posts from the taxonomy page im on, for example `http://comisionpais.com/comision-publicaciones/salud/`

Only load the post that have 'salud' marked.

This image shows all the loop
[http://imgur.com/a/hSgmX](https://imgur.com/a/hSgmX)

Why I pasted first code and last code, if it can help in something.